# Integer in while loop wont increase value

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm having a problem in my code, I am trying to append a number to a filename if filename already exists. It goes something like this

```
$explode = explode(".", $fileName);
$extension = end($explode);
$fileactualname = reset($explode);
$i = 0;
while (file_exists($location.$fileName)) {
    $i++;
}
$fileName= $i.$fileName;
$name = $fileName;
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $location . "/". $name);
if ($moveResult != true) {
    @unlink($fileTmpLoc);
    header('location: ' . URL . '?page=0&sort=name&type=desc&folder=uploads/&message=uploaderror');
}
```

Unfortunately for some reason `$i` wont increase its value by 1 every time it loops, instead it adds to the filename this way `1234filename.jpg` my file name variable is after the loop and i cant understand why this is accruing. I am expecting to get ($i)filename.jpg a single number
**AFTER RESTARTING MY LOCALSERVER IT STARTED WORKING WITH THE CODE PROVIDED BELOW DUUUH**

Comment: `$fileName= $i.$fileName;` should be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: I put it inside, same result

Comment: Edit your question with the updated code. And add what result you were expecting.

Comment: The problem is not with `$i`, but with `$fileName`: you change it each iteration, and keep appending numbers to it

Comment: Its the same thing other way

Comment: @Areg No idea what that comment means. Can you elaborate? Karsten has spotted the issue with the 1234 instead of 4 in the filename.

Comment: @Jonnix I tried moving the filename outside of the while loop it still produces the same result

Comment: OP, can you clarify what you code currently looks like?

Comment: Added what it looks like now

Comment: You've completely ignored the main points people are telling you. Just use Riggs' code.

Comment: @Jonnix then what exactly should happen?

Comment: Just reread Riggs answer. Slowly, line by line, taking care with where the variable names change. Your solution is right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the actual filename when you concat the number to it and not the one you already added a number to.

```
// not sure why you are splitting the filname up here
$explode = explode(".", $fileName);
$extension = end($explode);
$fileactualname = reset($explode);

$i = 0;
$fn = $fileName;

while (file_exists($location.$fn)) {
    $i++;
    // add number to actual filename
    $fn = $i.$fileName;
}

$name = $fn;
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $location . "/". $name);
```